# Uniquely identify a Computer by it's hardware profile (GetCurrentHwProfile)

Tags: c++

Using the GetCurrentHwProfile , we can retrieve the szHwProfileGuid, which is the hardware profile GUID of the machine, i suppose.

what is exactly a hardware profile and how is it editable?
is the Hardware profile GUID unique by machine?
Is the value stored somewhere in the registry and is it updatable?
If it is not unique, when exactly does this value change?

Comment: Just a guess, but you can specify 'hardware profiles' at boot time and  there is a built-in OS facility to save profiles. Useful for rolling back after driver/software setup. I think mostly it keeps a copy of the registry at a point in time, but... UPDATE: It appears this feature was removed after WinXP.

Comment: Well i just used this method on a 64bit windows 7 and it returned to me a GUID.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is just an [accessor to the registry key](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237387)

> HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\IDConfigDB\Hardware Profiles

And as [someone discovered](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.vb/2007-07/msg00656.html) none of the following affects it: changing Primary HD, adding a second HD, re-Installing or upgrading the OS, replacing video cards, or changing user. Changing network card *would* surely affect it, as it is involved in the creation of any GUID.

My guess is it was just a way to tell whether a laptop is docked, that was designed as a base for accessing a broader range hardware changes -  but that never really took place. 'Hardware profile' would probably stay a vague term forever, in this API context.

Comment: Good link, although it says that changing the primary HD and upgrading the OS DOES change it.  :-)  Also you can manually edit the key, not sure what effect that has and not sure on its reliability based on that.